# How to retrieve value from another database table in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5

I have two table named `users` and `profiles`.In `users` table its have a column named `id` and in `profiles` table its have a column named `userID`.Now i want when `users` table increasing `id` then `userID` automatic fill up respectively.

If anyone create profile then the `userID` column auto fill up according to the login `users` table `id`.How can i do that?

**User Model:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table ="users";
    protected $fillable = [
        'userName', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function profileHave(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile','userID');
    }
}
```

**Profile Model:**

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = "profiles";
    public $fillable = ["userID","firstName","lastName","middleName","DOB","gender","featuredProfile","email","phone","summary","profilePic"];

    public function userHave(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','userID');
   }
}
```

But when i add a profile with an user then in `profiles` table `userID` column is blank.But it should be fill up according to login id of the `users` table.

By the way i am new in Laravel.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the user id like this

```
$id = Auth::id();
```

and then assign this value to user property in profile like

```
$profile->userID = $id
```

Comment: I really don't understand where i add those?

Comment: when you save profile data to database
to save data in laravel you have to create a profile object and then fill all it's properties like so
`$profile = new Profile()
$profile->firstName = 'test'
$profile->lastName= 'test'
$profile->userID =  Auth::id();
$profile->save()`

Comment: Its shows when i saving `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found`

Comment: you pastebin link show me a 404 error and to remove auth not found error please  use the  Auth class nampspace
`use \Auth' at the top of your code

Comment: Now shows `Attempt to assign property of non-object` this error.

Answer (score 0):

When saving a profile, add a user to it with:

```
$profile->userHave = $user
```

A couple of things:

- Your `Profile` model does not need `userID` to be fillable. This is filled by your relation so really shouldn't be fillable.
- The relation is named a bit weirdly. It should really be the name of the attribute that you expect to use to fetch the relation. For instance, I would call the user relation in your profile just `user`:

  ```
  public function user()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User','userID');
  }
  ```

  With this, you would add a user to a profile with the following:

  ```
  $profile->user = $user;
  ```
- Lastly, **think about whether you actually need a profile model**.

  All the attributes in your profile model are attributes of the user. If you plan on having a profile for every user, you have no reason to have a different model for a profile.

Comment: where i add `$profile->user = $user;` this? in userController?

Comment: It depends. Where are you creating / saving your profiles? Put it there.

Comment: You need to fetch the user you want to add the profile to. `$user = User::find(1);`